# How can i auto add the name values from Dynamically Text Fields in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a form if someone select Persons Kids Or Babys, the total of persons will count and  A Passengerlist will appear based on the total of persons , they have to fill each passenger information in it.

Each input name will have a different name  `<input name=" ">` like `"passenger_name_1"` for the second passenger will it be : `"passenger_name_2"`.

Now if someone select 1 person and fill te data on the form, i will get the results of the value BUT only passenger_name_1 but how can i do that if someone select 5 persons, that i will get all the 5 persons information ?

You can check it on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9rspxhjy/3/)

So if the total persons is 5, there should be added this values in me php file and send the filled values :

```
'Passenger 1: ' . $_POST['passenger_name_1'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_lname_1'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_age_1'] . "<br />";
'Passenger 2: ' . $_POST['passenger_name_2'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_lname_2'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_age_2'] . "<br />";
'Passenger 3: ' . $_POST['passenger_name_3'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_lname_3'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_age_3'] . "<br />";
'Passenger 4: ' . $_POST['passenger_name_4'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_lname_4'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_age_4'] . "<br />";
'Passenger 5: ' . $_POST['passenger_name_5'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_lname_5'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_age_5'] . "<br />";
```

This is my PHP

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['bestemming']))
{
$to = 'myemail@mail.com';
$subject = "Reservation";
$message = 

'Trip: ' . $_POST['bestemming'] . "<br /><br />" . 
'Persons: ' . $_POST['vol'] . "<br />" . 
'Kids: ' . $_POST['kinderen'] . "<br />" . 
'Babys: ' . $_POST['babys'] . "<br /><br />" . 

'Passenger infomation: ' . $_POST['passenger_name_1'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_lname_1'] . " " . $_POST['passenger_age_1'] . "<br />";

// Define the main headers.

$headers = 'From:' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'Reply-To:' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers.= "boundary=$num\r\n";
$headers.= "--$num\r\n";

// Define the message section

$headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n\n";
$headers.= "$message\r\n";
$headers.= "--$num\r\n";

// Send email

mail($to, $subject, '', $headers);
}
```

For the automatic adding the fields based on the Total Persons is this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(document).on('change', '.count-select', function () {
        sum = 0;
        $('.count-select').each(function () {
            console.log($(this));
            var thisVal = parseInt($(this).val());
            sum += thisVal;
        });
        $('#person-total').text(sum);
        // you can use here 

        // remove all divs
        $('div[class^="passenger"]').remove();
        // to show divs depending on number of persons
        for (var i = 1; i <= sum; i++) {
            $('.passengerlistinfo').append('<div class="passenger"> <div class="form-group col-md-4 passe"><label for="name"></label> <b>Passenger ' + i + ' </b> <br> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FirstName" name="passenger_name_' + i + '" ></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><label for="name"></label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="LastName" name="passenger_lname_' + i + '" ></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><label for="name"></label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" name="passenger_age_' + i + '" ></div></div></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you'd need to include `$_POST['passenger_name_5']` and whatnot in your mail script. a better method be to build in a loop - pass in another field that contains how many fields were added, then use a `for` loop to access each of those fields in turn. `for ($i ...) { $foo = $_POST["name_$i"]; }`

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! That i was thinking .. I need a loop! But how can i add that? Just paste your code in my php? But for what are the 3 dots?

Comment: What about creating an array of inputs with the `passenger_name` name attribute so  you can loop over that array in PHP? E.g. `<input name="passenger_name[0]" /><input name="passenger_name[1]" />`. Then in PHP you can use something like `foreach($_POST['passenger_name'] as $index => $name) {/*go nuts*/}`. You can also omit the integers and just use `passenger_name[]`, I like to place the integers in there to make sure the name (in this case) lines up with any other input for the same index.

Comment: Hi Jasper, thanks yes i can change `passenger_name_1` in `passenger_name[1]` but where i do need to place the `foreach($_POST['passenger_name'] as $index => $name) {/*go nuts*/}` ? And what you mean about go nuts?

Comment: @MissesSalima By "go nuts" i just mean do whatever you wanted to do with the different inputs. It looks like you just want to list out the passenger names, so inside the loop do that. `foreach($_POST['passenger_name'] as $index => $name) { $message .= 'Passenger ' . ($index + 1) . ': ' . $name . ' ' . $_POST['passenger_lname'][$index] . ' ' . $_POST['passenger_age'][$index] . '<br />'; }`. I assume you'll start at a zero index with the inputs, so in my example I added one to each index when creating your `$message` output.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks men, i still can not get it work in PHP, check https://jsfiddle.net/mcrbb7hp/

Comment: @MissesSalima JSFiddle is just for JS/CSS/HTML, PHP will not actually run. To figure this out I recommend updating your JS to output the new input names using the array paradigm, then go to your PHP and use `print_r($_POST)` to see exactly how PHP sees the data. Then go ahead and create your loop since you will have a solid understanding of how your data is structured. Also when you're developing make sure to display errors, I usually place this at the top of my development scripts: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors', 1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Jasper Ok i will try, can you maybe edit and post the right php? How it should be? I will appreciate that :)

Comment: @Jasper It works i think , but the results not showing on me mail : `Array ( [bestemming] => Paris [vol] => 3 [kinderen] => 0 [babys] => 0 [passenger_name_] => Array ( [1] => firstFieldname [2] => secondFieldName [3] => ThirdFieldName ) [passenger_lname_1] => firstFieldLastname [passenger_age_1] => firstFieldAge [passenger_lname_2] => secondFieldLastName [passenger_age_2] => secondFieldAge [passenger_lname_3] => ThirdFieldLastName [passenger_age_3] => ThirdFieldAge ) `

Comment: @MissesSalima This will be my last response since I have to leave my computer but my code assumed that you updated all the passenger information inputs to the `[]` array version (including age and last name). The print-out of your `$_POST` data shows that you didn't do that. Also the `passenger_name` field has the trailing underscore so it won't be accessible unless you use that underscore in the `foreach` loop. In general though, first setup your front-end to supply data correctly, then look how your back-end is receiving the data, then create your logic based on that information.

Comment: It is now : `Array ( [bestemming] => Paris [vol] => 2 [kinderen] => 0 [babys] => 0 [passenger_name] => Array ( [1] => hi [2] => doei ) [passenger_lname] => Array ( [1] => firstnm [2] => second ) [passenger_age] => Array ( [1] => ok [2] => ok ) ) ` Anyway thanks for your help, i still not see it as post mail

Comment: I see as results: Array,, pff so annoying this, cant get out of it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you

```
<?php


    $count = 1;
    $next = true;

    while($next==true){

        //check if passenger_n exits
        if(isset($_POST['passenger_name_'.$count])){
            $message .='Passenger infomation: ' . $_POST['passenger_name_'.$count] . 
                " " . $_POST['passenger_lname_'.$count] . " 
                " . $_POST['passenger_age_'.$count] . "<br />";
        }else{
            //finish the loop
            $next = false;
        }
        //increase the passenger id
        $count++;
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bit of an anti-pattern in naming your inputs with name like `passenger_name_*`.

You should consider just defining name as `passenger_name[]`.  The `[]` connote input field names which should be considered as part of an array when POSTed to the server.  PHP will in pfact take values posted with such names and assemble them into a nice array available as `$_POST['passenger_name']`.

This greatly simplifies both server-side and client-side code in that it eliminates the need for you to keep counters on how many of these similarly-named fields exist.  So, on the client-side, you can easily add or remove inputs using only this common name (no needed to calculate how many there are and apply some "index" value like `_1` onto the end of the input name.

On the server side you just access the array in `$_POST` and again they will be automatically numerically indexed for you, so you don't have to check for a bunch of variables like `$_POST['passenger_name_1']`, `$_POST['passenger_name_2']`, etc.

Comment: thanks, yes i already changed it to passenger_name[1] etc. but how make the $_POST automatically in PHP ?

Comment: @MissesSalima I would not even specify the index explicitly if you don't have to (just using as `[]` simplifies your code from having to maintain counters).  PHP will automatically take any parameters with names ending in `[]` or `[*]` and compile them to any array at `$_POST['name of field']`, as long as you are using one of the form-related content types, which you are (though you should probably be using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` since you are not doing a file upload). In your case, the arraywould be available in `$_POST['passenger_name']`, based on what you have shown.

Comment: Thanks! so my post is now : `'Personsinformation: ' .$_POST['passenger_name']. "<br><br>".` and i have a array like :  `foreach($_POST['passenger_name'] as $index => $name) { $message .= 'Passenger ' . ($index + 1) . ': ' . $name . ' ' . $_POST['passenger_lname'][$index] . ' ' . $_POST['passenger_age'][$index] . '<br />'; }`
The output is good now, but i see "Array" as results instead the filled values

Comment: @MissesSalima If you try to echo out `$_POST['passenger_name']` like you are showing here, you are going top get `Array` in your output.  It is an array and not meant to be echoed out directly.